# Why have I been banned from asking questions?

Tags: discussion, post-ban

I've been banned from asking questions, because I discuss topics which the far-left moderators here regard as being "wrongthink". They want politics.SE to remain a "safe space" for establishment/leftist views, and because I've crossed the line by discussing inconvenient facts surrounding race and immigration, and cite reliable sources in my answers (as opposed to "fake news" sources like CNN, NYT), I have been banned.

This is censorship. It's quite despicable, frankly. Is it not possible to have a grown-up conversation about these issues?

Answer (score 17):

Your account was automatically banned from posting questions. No moderators, far-left or otherwise, were directly involved. This site is a shared resource, asking questions here is a privilege. The system reacted to what it considered to be an abuse of this privilege.

Of the ten questions you have asked, only three were positively received from the community. The rest were heavily downvoted, closed and deleted:

- (0) [What are the causes of American political polarization?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/21995/what-are-the-causes-of-american-political-polarization)
- (-7) [Why do many Jews tend to be hypocritical in their support for open borders?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/23557/101)
- (-4) [What were the negative effects of the Civil Rights Act, if any?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/23856/101)
- (-6) [What would be the logistical implications of using the US military to deport illegal aliens?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/27541/101)
- (-9) [Does the influence Mexican nationals have on US politics constitute a form of foreign interference?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/27595/101)
- (-6) [Are modern Western countries the most “equal” with respect to ethnicity in human history?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/32755/101)
- (-7) [Why aren't whites in the United States allowed to express their collective political interests?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/32910/101)

I think it's clear that the community does not welcome your questions. You can, of course, claim that the only reason for this is your politics. If that is what you believe, I won't try to convince you otherwise.

If, on the other hand, you are interested in contributing positively to this site in the future, I invite you to examine your past questions and ask yourself:

- Are my questions within the [scope defined by the community](https://politics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)?
- Are my questions clear and to the point?
- Have I done a good job of documenting my research?
- Have I done a good job supporting any non-trivial claims?
- Is my tone as neutral as possible?
- Was I responsive to feedback and requests for clarification?

---

Further reading:

- [What topics can I ask about here?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)
- [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)
- [How do I ask a good question?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)
- [Why are questions no longer being accepted from my account?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/help/question-bans)
- [Help! I am being oppressed! Why do people keep downvoting my opinions?](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2655/101)
- [A full and objective description of good faith?](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3040/101)
- [Should we encourage questions to be rewritten in nonpartisan terms?](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/254/101)

---

PS. You mention your answers. Although your answers suffer from several issues, they are not relevant to your question ban. At this time you are not blocked from posting answers.

Answer (score 11):

> They want politics.SE to remain a "safe space" for establishment/leftist views

When you make a claim that goes against establishment views (as you do in this meta post), please include the evidence that convinces you the status quo (regarding the content of your post) is wrong.

For example, when you claim that CNN or the NYT (sources others deem reputable) are fake news, you should support that with convincing evidence (or post them on Skeptics SE to see if they might fact-check them). Note that a conspiracy theorist's website or their theories are not convincing sources.

> This is censorship. It's quite despicable, frankly. Is it not possible to have a grown-up conversation about these issues?

Just like you have the right to free speech (in your country, not on specific websites), people on this website have the right not to take heed of your posts. When your posts don't meet community standards, users will vote them down and ultimately delete them. When this happens too often, the site automatically prevents you from posting because it expects (based on past behaviour) that the new posts won't meet the standards either.

In addition to that, this isn't really the place for conversations. This is a Q&A site for asking questions that can be answered based on facts. That's not possible if a question has a false premise or is aggressively phrased to push an agenda. If you really want to have conversations, I suggest having them on a different site that allows and is designed for having discussions.